# How to retrieve collection name based on item?

Tags: sql, dspace

I am doing dspace search project. Here I have created seperate item page. Now I have one problem. I am not able to retrieve collection name in in which item appears. Collection2item displays only collection id.Please help.

Comment: any example code snap? It will help us

Comment: I don't get it, sorry Savio. Try to get to the concrete point on where you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Savio, thank you for clarifying that you are in DSpace 5.

The following code appears to document the migration of community.name from DSpace 4 to DSpace 5.

https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-api/src/main/resources/org/dspace/storage/rdbms/sqlmigration/postgres/V5.0_2014.09.26__DS-1582_Metadata_For_All_Objects.sql#L133-L141

DSpace 5 introduced "metadata for all objects" and collection.name appears to be stored as a metadatavalue of "title".

Answer (score 1):

The collection name is stored in the collection table. It is linked to the item table via `item.owning_collection` and `collection2item`.

```
select collection.name 
from collection 
inner join item on owning_collection=collection_id
where item_id=1
```

Comment: The question is tagged [java]. Are you sure you got the topic? I guess this isn't Java code.

Comment: dspace 5 doesn't have collection name in collection table